# Is it possible to change ringing sound of Skype for iOS

Tags: skype, ios, ipad

Does anybody know how to change the default ringing sound of Skype for iOS? 
Their standard sound is too soft and hard to hear. I've complained to their support several times and asked on their forum - not a single answer!
Am I the only one who wants a different ringing sound?

Comment: did you try this "on iOS: From the home screen, tap Settings (gear icon) > Notifications, then tap Allow Notifications to turn them on or off." and would that work for you.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Is my iOS too old (9.3.5)? There is no such choice in my Settings under Notifications. I have only a list of all apps there, and all possible notifications for Skype are on. Next idea, please?